# Confusion regarding usage of "has" and "is"

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is correct :

> 1. A plane has crashed in USA today.
> 2. A plane is crashed in USA today.

Comment: Unrelated to the question of "has" versus "is": you should write "in the USA" instead of "in USA".

Answer (score 1):

The form you are looking for is the [*present perfect*](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-perfect), which is built with the auxiliary verb *have* and the past participle.

So the correct form is "A plane has crashed in the USA today." This sentence describes a recent event.

When you use the auxiliary verb "be" before a past participle, you are not describing a recent event but a state or an outcome. For example: "My homework is finished."

Another case where you use "be" before a past participle is the passive voice. For example: "The plane was crashed deliberately by the the co-pilot". (See the [GermanWings crash in March 2015](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/germanwings-crash-full-transcript-of-press-conference-10136377.html).)

Comment: I read somewhere on internet : a plane was crashed in xyz location

Comment: @user188386 I assume you saw a passive sentence and that you quote only part of it. It is also possible that "was crashed" was a typo (for "has crashed") or that it was written by a non-native speaker of English.

Comment: Strobbe , "he was **released** on bail". Here **released** after the form **to be**,   has it been used for  passive voice ? Or   used as an adjective?

Comment: @user188386 "He was released on bail" is a clear example of the passive voice.